# Good reference material for creating VS2008 integration packages

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense, vsinstaller

I'm looking for reference/tutorial material on building integration packages for Visual Studio 2008.

I am particularly looking for info on editor integration such as **intellisense** for a custom syntax (and contained languages) and **source code formatting/coloring**.

I found [some info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166580(VS.80).aspx) on the Microsoft MSDN site, but as always, the information found there creates more confusion than enlightenment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the Visual Studio SDK. This and many other resources are available at the [Visual Studio Extensibility Developer Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsx/default.aspx).

Comment: I already had the Visual Studio SDK installed, but the information is really confusing. I'm sure I could figure it out somehow, but there must be some "Getting Started" info available somewhere...

Comment: Well, no, there isn't. The next best thing would be for you to get "Professional Visual Studio Extensibility", by Keyvan Nayyeri (http://www.amazon.com/Professional-Visual-Studio-Extensibility-Nayyeri/dp/0470230843/ref=pd_bbs_sr_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1207346558&sr=8-1), which goes from Macros to Add-Ins, and all the way up. BTW, if you want to do these things for VS2008 and below, you've picked a tough area that's changing radically in VS2010.

Comment: Is the Developer Center of no help? Make sure you click the various tabs. It's not just one page. For instance, the Nayyeri book was listed at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsx/cc677062.aspx, which is under "Learn", then "Books".

Comment: And did you find the page on "Editors" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsx/cc677249.aspx)?